# jQuery table add class for the first matching tbody and add class for last matching tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my markup like this

```
<table class="section-table">
        <thead class="found">
            <tr>
                <th>data 1</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="found">
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody class="found">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>data 1</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead class="found">
            <tr>
                <th>data 1</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="found">
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="found">
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now here you can see that in some thead there is class called found. Here in the tbody there is also some tbody has class found. Now I want in jQuery after the thead which has class found it will get the next first tbody which has class found tbody and add class first-row and the last tbody which has class found will be last-row. So basically the out put should be like

```
<table class="section-table">
        <thead class="found">
            <tr>
                <th>data 1</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="found first-row">
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody class="found last-row">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>data 1</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead class="found">
            <tr>
                <th>data 1</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="found first-row">
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="found last-row">
            <tr>
                <td>data test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have tried this

```
jQuery('table.section-table').find('thead.found').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).next('tbody.found').addClass('first-row');
    jQuery(this).prev('tbody.found').addClass('last-row');
  });
```

Comment: A `<table>` can only have one `<thead>` - you have invalid html (other wise you would have used `jQuery(this).siblings('tbody.found').first().addClass('first-row');`)

Comment: yes I understand this is invalid html but the structure is like that.

Comment: `</tbody class="found last-row">` - you can not put any attributes on the closing _tag_ of an element, and neither can you select the tags themselves, you can only select the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invalid html (a `<table>` can have multiple `<tbody>` elements, but only have one `<thead>` element. Because of that, you will not be able to use normal selectors such as

```
('tbody').siblings('tbody').first().addClass('first-row')
```

Instead you will need to loop each element to in the `<table>`

```
var foundFirst = false;
$('table').children('.found').each(function(index, item){
    if ($(this).is('thead')) {
        foundFirst = false; // reset for next set of tbody elements
    } else {
        if (!foundFirst) {
            $(this).addClass('first-row')
            foundFirst = true; // toggle
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('last-row')
        }
    }
})
```

Note the above assumes there will not be more that two `<tbody class="found">` in the group following a `<thead>` element

Answer (score 0):

just do this :

```
jQuery('table.section-table').find('thead').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).next().find('tbody.found:first').addClass('first-row');
    jQuery(this).next().find('tbody.found:last').addClass('last-row');
});
```

Comment: could you log this line jQuery(this).next().find('tbody.found:first')

Comment: i mean log that line and see what is in that